# What frameworks/db offer a good solution for content-based filtering?

Tags: database-design, neo4j, recommendation-engine, database, nosql

Let's say I have 700 000 observations of products which have certain attributes, lets call them tags.

And lets say we have userX. I want to implement a simple content-based filtering method: rank the products based by the tag count / relevance.
So lets say userX has a preference for:
- yellow
- price (0-15)
- brandname

To get a recommendation, one would need to go over all 700.000 observations (can be done in a noSQL database normalization setting through tags, but still can be a lot observations when there are multiple tags involved), and count the number of tags that are present in a certain product.

What framework or method could I use to do this quickly? I.e. to get the outcome within a couple of seconds?

Some things I thought were:

- pure nodejs server
- pure python server
- neo4j graph database, but not sure how relations could be implemented in this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the product "observations" include user purchases/interactions? If so, in a graph database like neo4j you could model the data like this:

[image]

Here you have a user who purchased a product, where that product has one or more tag attributes. To generate a content based recommendation you could then use a Cypher query like this:

```
MATCH (u:User {name: "Bob"})-[:PURCHASED]->(p:Product)
MATCH (p)-[:TAGGED]->(t:Tag)
MATCH (t)<-[:TAGGED]-(rec:Product) WHERE NOT (u)-[:PURCHASED]->(rec)
RETURN rec, count(*) AS weight ORDER BY weight DESC
```

This query essentially says: "Find all the products that Bob has purchased. Find the tags for those products. Now find products with those same tags that Bob has not purchased. Recommend these products to Bob, showing the products with the highest number of overlapping tags first."

More information on this is available [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_0Iuc3zUN4) and [in this tutorial](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-build-a-recommendation-engine/).

Comment: For a real world example this [blog post](http://neo4j.com/blog/date-night-movie-neo4j/) was just published today which details content based recommendations for movies.

Comment: I just have to add: I have 700.000 items, and the nb of purchases should be max 50 per user. Can neo4j handle this performance wise?

Comment: @JoshAndrews yes, no problem. Many Neo4j users have graphs with millions of nodes/relationships.

Comment: Quick follow up (after a year). If there was a weight attached to the tag and the purchased, e.g. t.weight and p.rating. So the user rates a product when purchasing; then find the products with greatest tag similarity (more weight to the tags that belong to the products that the user has purchased and thus rated)